# checkbox "Add CREATE DATABASE / USE statement" not in $cfg[export]

Tags: phpmyadmin, export, settings

"Add CREATE DATABASE / USE statement" checkbox is unchecked by default (phpmyadmin 4.1.12). 
Is there a way to change the default state? 
I can't find setting in $cfg[export], nor in Settings tab

Location : Export > SQL > Format-specific options > Object creation options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit tricky to find, but `$cfg['Export']['sql_create_database'] = true;` should accomplish what you want. Add that line in `config.inc.php` and you should be all set.

`./libraries/config.default.php` has a boatload of export configuration options that aren't individually documented in the user documentation but can come in handy. In order to use them, you should copy them to your `config.inc.php` rather than directly editing the default file.